# Looking for equivalent of Indian (Marathi) saying "Makdach ghar" which translates "Monkey's house"(never ready when you expect it should be)

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions, idioms, pejorative-language

I am looking for equivalent of Indian saying "Makdach ghar" which is "Monkey's house" the meaning is a monkey always starts to built his house only after it starts to rain. It has the analogy of "Ants and the grasshopper" where the monkey = the grasshopper

I am not looking for the saying like "Stitch in time saves nine" as that is more suggestive of an advice, rather it should be a phrase reflecting the ill effect. The monkey's house as per local culture here reflects the idea that the house (or the monkey's action or inaction) is ineffective, ill conceived for a heavy rainy season and will not stand a chance.

Friend 1 to Friend 2 (working in other company): The management in our company is so damn frustrating, we are plagued by inaction. Now our cash-cow client is expected to pays us a visit from the US. This is their first visit since last 10 years of our business relationship and our yard is __________ (monkey's house - which is never ready for the presentation or circumstance presented). It would have been better if they had stitched in time.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're after idioms:

---

***[House of cards](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/house%20of%20cards)***
*This place is a house of cards.*

> a structure, situation, or institution that is insubstantial, shaky, or in constant danger of collapse

---

***[Caught with their trousers down.](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+caught+with+their+trousers+down)***
*If the client shows up, we'll be caught with our trousers down.*

> To be taken by surprise; to be caught in a vulnerable (often embarrassing) position or situation.

---

***[Always a day late and a dollar short](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/day+late+and+a+dollar+short)***

> late and ill-prepared.

Answer (score 2):

The closest I can think of is ***disarray*** - a state of affairs close to what you have described.

> ... This is their first visit since last 10 years of our business
>   relationship and our yard is in ***disarray***. ...

ODO:

> **[disarray](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/disarray)**
>   *NOUN*   [mass noun]
>   A state of disorganization or untidiness.
>
> ‘Our residence in Baker Street had the reputation of being cluttered
>   and in disarray, so perhaps he thought this was its normal
>   appearance.’